# Building a wxWidgets project in VS Code

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, wxwidgets, fedora

I try to start using Linux(Fedora 33) and now I've got a trouble. I want to use VS Code and it builds simple cpp projects correctly, but I want to make GUI using wxWidgets. So I created simple example, but it doesn't want to build it. I installed wxWidgets from rpm package. I also added pathes into includePath in configuration file. Now I want to show you the code and errors.

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

int main() { return 0; }
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ сборка активного файла",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "компилятор: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Сборка и отладка активного файла",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Включить автоматическое               форматирование для gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ сборка активного файла",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/**",
                "/usr/lib64/wx/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Now, there are no errors given me by intellisence, I think.

Compilers errors:

```
 Запуск сборки…
 /usr/bin/g++ -g /home/nikita/Workfiles/wxex/main.cpp -o /home/nikita/Workfiles/wxex/main
/home/nikita/Workfiles/wxex/main.cpp:1:10: фатальная ошибка: wx/wxprec.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
1 | #include <wx/wxprec.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
 компиляция прервана.
 
Сборка завершена с ошибками.
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with errors as text not images

Comment: @NikitaSimonenko, please don't use the screenshot when posting here. Some people are blind and they won't be able to help you. And some people are behind a firewall or on a restricted network - and they will not be able to help you. So you cut off the people who wants to help but couldn't. Please don't do that. TIA!

Comment: I also don't see where did you put the proper include directories based on you compilation command. Please fix your project and then your code will compile.

Comment: Sorry, It's my first question here, so didn't think about the details. I'll edit my questions, when I have time. Thank you for your advices!

Comment: @Nikitasimonenko, please install wx sample code and try to build minimal sample. You will see that the path you use is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
```

with

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
```

Comment: what's wrong with the original code? Unless the OP somehow screwed up the directories this code is perfectly legal. I'd also suggest to use `""` instead of `<>` for wx headers.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to use "" and it didn't work.

Comment: I also tried to write only   `#include <wx/wx.h>`, but it still doesn't work. But thank you.

Comment: "Still doesn't work"!!  What doesn't work?  Are you getting a build error?  What is it?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error as in my question.

Comment: Really?  Your original error referred to wxprec.  Having removed that, you are claiming you are still getting the same error?!?!

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets provides `wx-config` script under Unix which must be used to obtain the options necessary for compiling and linking programs using the library. Please run `wx-config --cxxflags` to obtain the full flags you need to put in your `c_cpp_properties.json` and also `wx-config --libs` to get the linker flags that you will need to use to make the program link, and not just compile, successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As the person who starts using Linux AND wants to learn new library id recommend followinh:

1. Grab the source code from [www.wxwidget.org/download](http://www.wxwidget.org/download)
2. Unpack it somewhere
3. Open the terminal
4. cd wxWidgets-3.1.4
5. mkdir buildGTK
6. cd buildGTK
7. ../configure --enable-debug
8. make
9. cd samples/minimal
10. Make

Now the last `make` command will display everything you need to include and link against. You will also have a samples code you can refer to when needed.

If you don't want to build the library from source - try the following

1. Open terminal
2. Type "which wx-config" (without quotes) and press ebter
3. Run "/path/to/wx-config --cxxflags" (without quots)
4. Run "/path/to/wx-config --libs" (without quotes)

Use the output from the commands above in you IDE.

HTH.